# Update QEMU on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kvm-virtualization, qemu

Currently Ubuntu 12.04 comes with QEMU 1.0, and I would like to update this to a newer version (1.5/1.6) to achieve maximum performance.

However, there doesn't seem to be an apt package for versions > 1.0. Is it safe to install this from source or will it break my system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating QEMU to its recent version will not break your Ubuntu installation. One of the users had already tried that and posted the result on his blog. Here is the link, [alinush.org](http://alinush.org/2013/02/19/how-to-compilebuild-qemu-1-4-0-on-ubuntu-12-04/).

The current QEMU installation is with version 1.2.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm

Comment: Author of question said that uses Ubuntu 12.04, so v1.2 isn't @ his system.

Comment: Anybody know of a PPA for this instead of compiling?

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled QEMU 2.0 myself on Ubuntu 12.04 and wrote down what I did to be successful:

*[Building QEMU 2.0](http://michigreat.a.wiki-site.com/index.php/Building_Qemu_2.0)*

I hope that helps anyone.